# Dynamically Change windows for NavigationWindow in appcelerator ios

Tags: dynamic, navigation, window, load, appcelerator

I need to show the multiple windows under the single `Titanium.UI.iOS.NavigationWindow`. I need to show those windows dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Titanium.UI.iOS.NavigationWindow is really meant to hold multiple windows with some predefined features like back button, sweet open/close animations.

Following the example from Ti Docs:

```
var win2 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    title: 'Red Window'
});

var win1 = Titanium.UI.iOS.createNavigationWindow({
   window: win2
});

var win3 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    title: 'Blue Window'
});

var button = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Open Blue Window'
});
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    win1.openWindow(win3, {animated:true});
});

win2.add(button);
var button2 = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Close Blue Window'
});
button2.addEventListener('click', function(){
    win1.closeWindow(win3, {animated:false}); //win3.close() will also work!!
});

win3.add(button2);
win1.open();
```

You can test in above code how to open/close window(s), with optional open/close animation.